# Mysql search message for no results and clear querystring before search?

Tags: php, mysql, search, query-string

I have been having some difficulty getting a no results found message to appear after a search query using a search form. my code below.  Could someone please help.

I would also like to be able to clear my query string once a search is submitted at the moment if I'm on page 3 for example and then do a search with my form, i get no results displayed as i'm already on page 3 because of the query string that's set. Hope that makes sense.

```
function supportquery($viewstate) {

 $display = 6;// number of results per page

        if (isset($_GET['np'])) {
    $num_pages = $_GET['np'];
} else {

    $where = "1"; // default
    switch ($viewstate) {
        case "open": $where = "status='Open'"; break;
        case "pending": $where = "status LIKE 'Pending%'"; break;
        case "closed": $where = "status='Closed'"; break;
    }

    $query = "SELECT ticket_number, first_name, surname, email, product, retailer, DATE_FORMAT(dop, '%d %M %Y') AS dop,
        message, address, DATE_FORMAT(created, '%d %M %Y %r') AS created, status FROM support_dev WHERE $where ORDER BY ticket_number DESC";
        $search = "%" . $_POST["search"] . "%";
    if ($_POST["search"]) { $query = "SELECT ticket_number, first_name, surname, email, product, retailer, DATE_FORMAT(dop, '%d %M %Y') AS dop, message, address, DATE_FORMAT(created, '%d %M %Y %r') AS created, status FROM support_dev WHERE ticket_number LIKE '$search' OR email LIKE '$search' ORDER BY ticket_number DESC"; 

}

    $query_result = mysql_query ($query); 
    $num_records = @mysql_num_rows ($query_result);
    if ($num_records > $display) {
        $num_pages = ceil ($num_records/$display);
    } else {
        $num_pages = 1;
    }
}



if (isset($_GET['startoftable'])) {
    $start = $_GET['startoftable'];
} else {
    $start = 0;// start of results from row 0 in table

}

    $query = "SELECT ticket_number, first_name, surname, email, product, retailer, DATE_FORMAT(dop, '%d %M %Y') AS dop, message, address, DATE_FORMAT(created, '%d %M %Y %r') AS created, status FROM support_dev ORDER BY ticket_number DESC LIMIT $start, $display";
    if ($viewstate=='open') {

        $query = "SELECT ticket_number, first_name, surname, email, product, retailer, DATE_FORMAT(dop, '%d %M %Y') AS dop, message, address, DATE_FORMAT(created, '%d %M %Y %r') AS created, status FROM support_dev WHERE status='Open'ORDER BY ticket_number DESC LIMIT $start, $display";
        }
            elseif ($viewstate=='pending') {
        $query = "SELECT ticket_number, first_name, surname, email, product, retailer, DATE_FORMAT(dop, '%d %M %Y') AS dop, message, address, DATE_FORMAT(created, '%d %M %Y %r') AS created, status FROM support_dev WHERE status LIKE 'Pending%' ORDER BY ticket_number DESC LIMIT $start, $display";
        }
        elseif ($viewstate=='closed') {
        $query = "SELECT ticket_number, first_name, surname, email, product, retailer, DATE_FORMAT(dop, '%d %M %Y') AS dop, message, address, DATE_FORMAT(created, '%d %M %Y %r') AS created, status FROM support_dev WHERE status='Closed' ORDER BY ticket_number DESC LIMIT $start, $display";}


    if ($_POST["search"]) {
         $query = "SELECT ticket_number, first_name, surname, email, product, retailer, DATE_FORMAT(dop, '%d %M %Y') AS dop, message, address, DATE_FORMAT(created, '%d %M %Y %r') AS created, status FROM support_dev WHERE ticket_number LIKE '$search' OR email LIKE '$search' ORDER BY ticket_number DESC LIMIT $start, $display";


      }

        $result = @mysql_query ($query);
        $num = mysql_num_rows ($result);

if ($num > 0) {

    if ($num_pages > 1) {
        echo '<div class="pagination"><p>';
        $current_page = ($start/$display) + 1; 

        if ($current_page != 1) {
            echo '<a href="?page_id=1072&amp;startoftable=' . (0) . '&np=' . $num_pages . '&viewstate=' . $viewstate .'">First</a> ';  
            echo '<a href="?page_id=1072&amp;startoftable=' . ($start - $display) . '&np=' . $num_pages . '&viewstate=' . $viewstate . '"><</a> ';
        }

    // range of num links to show
$range = 4;

// loop to show links to range of pages around current page
for ($i = ($current_page - $range); $i < (($current_page + $range)  + 1); $i++) {
   // if it's a valid page number...
   if (($i > 0) && ($i <= $num_pages)) {
      // if we're on current page...
      if ($i == $current_page) {
         // 'highlight' it but don't make a link
         echo " [<b>$i</b>] ";
      // if not current page...
      } else {
         // make it a link
     echo ' <a href="?page_id=1072&amp;startoftable=' . (($display * ($i - 1))) . '&np=' . $num_pages . '&viewstate=' . $viewstate .'">' .$i .'</a> ';

      }}}   

        if ($current_page != $num_pages) {

            echo '<a href="?page_id=1072&amp;startoftable=' . ($start + $display) . '&np=' . $num_pages . '&viewstate=' . $viewstate .'">></a> '; 
            echo '<a href="?page_id=1072&amp;startoftable=' . ( $display * $num_pages-$display ) . '&np=' . $num_pages . '&viewstate=' . $viewstate .'">Last</a> '; 
        }

        echo '</p></div> '; 

    }

         if ($result = mysql_query ($query)) {
         echo '
    <div id="supviewwrapperheader">
    <div id="supviewticket"><p>Ticket</p></div> 
    <div id="supviewfirst"><p>First Name</p></div>
    <div id="supviewlast"><p>Last Name</p></div>
    <div id="supviewemail"><p>Email</p></div>
    <div id="supviewproduct"><p>Product</p></div>
    <div id="supviewretailer"><p>Retailer</p></div>
    <div id="supviewdop"><p>D.O.P.</p></div>
    <div id="supviewmessage"><p>Message</p></div>
    <div id="supviewaddress"><p>Address</p></div>
    <div id="supviewcreated"><p>Date created</p></div>
    <div id="supviewstatus"><p>Status</p></div>
    <div id="supviewbuttons"><p></p></div>
    </div>
    ';

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        echo "
        <div id=\"supviewwrapper\" class=\"".($row[10])."\">
        <div id=\"supviewticket\"><p><a name=\"a".$row[0]."\"></a>$row[0]</p></div>
        <div id=\"supviewfirst\"><p>$row[1]</p></div>
        <div id=\"supviewlast\"><p>$row[2]</p></div>
        <div id=\"supviewemail\"><p>$row[3]</p></div>
        <div id=\"supviewproduct\"><p>$row[4]</p></div>
        <div id=\"supviewretailer\"><p>$row[5]</p></div>
        <div id=\"supviewdop\"><p>$row[6]</p></div>
        <div id=\"supviewmessage\"><p>$row[7]</p></div>
        <div id=\"supviewaddress\"><p>$row[8]</p></div>
        <div id=\"supviewcreated\"><p>$row[9]</p></div>
        <div id=\"supviewstatus\"><p>$row[10]</p></div>
        <div id=\"supviewbuttons\"><p><form method=\"post\" action=\"".htmlentities($_SERVER['REQUEST_URL'])."#a".$row[0]."\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"close_row\" value=\"".($row[0])."\" /><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"viewstate\" value=\"".$viewstate."\" /><INPUT TYPE=\"submit\" name=\"open\" VALUE=\"\" class=\"submit_open\"><br /><INPUT TYPE=\"submit\" name=\"pending\" VALUE=\"\" class=\"submit_pending\"><br /><INPUT TYPE=\"submit\" name=\"pending_ami\" VALUE=\"\" class=\"submit_pendingami\"><br /><INPUT TYPE=\"submit\" name=\"pending_arp\" VALUE=\"\" class=\"submit_pendingarp\"><br /><INPUT TYPE=\"submit\" name=\"close\" VALUE=\"\" class=\"submit_closed\"></form></p></div></div>";



    }


     }

    mysql_free_result ($result);

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `LIKE "%{$search}%"` to match a string within a string.

Comment: Hi thanks for the tip, still doesn't help with my other issues though.